# If statement can't change local variable

Tags: c#, if-statement

Why can't i change value with an if statement?

```
        int amount;
        string inputbalk = inputbar.Text;

        if (inputbalk== string.Empty)
        {
            amount = Convert.ToInt32(inputbalk);
            amount = 1;
        }

        if (inputbalk != string.Empty)
        {
            amount = Convert.ToInt32(inputbalk);
            amount = 1;
        }

        int onepercent = amount/= 100;
```

It will see "amount" as an unassigned variable, even though I set it to 1, by two different if-statements.

If I debug, I get this:
"Error  1   Use of unassigned local variable 'amount'"

---

Thanks for help guys, It is fixed/solved.

Comment: Debug the code, and see what happens.

Comment: What is an "empty variabel"? As far as I am aware a bit can only be set to 0 or 1, never "empty". Can you be more specific?

Comment: Try `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputbalk)) {` instead

Comment: "Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'amount'"

Comment: It's not an if loop, but an if statement. ;)

Comment: Why is the variable `onepercent` an int? What integer are you expecting? Shouldn't it be a float or double? Also watch out for integer division, which means that `amount /= 100` will be zero. I think you want `amount /= 100.0`.

Comment: this because 1/100= 0.01 as floating point and 0 as integer

Comment: Basically this code seems totally wrong. Perhaps you need to take a step back and ask what problem you are actually trying to solve and how best to do it? It looks like the problem can be solved by using TryParse, but the *real* problem here seems to be that you haven't read a tutorial on C# and are just trying to guess the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change second if to else

```
        if (inputbalk== string.Empty)
        {
            amount = Convert.ToInt32(inputbalk);
            amount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            amount = Convert.ToInt32(inputbalk);
            amount = 1;
        }
```

The compiler can't make sure that one of two if statements will work anyway, so it will throw error that your variable amount **can be** `unassigned`.

In `if/else` notation one of two code blocks will be done anyway, so compiler will not throw error and everything will work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because the chances are that you won't go into any if statement and thus leaving the amount as unassigned. You will get error on this line:

```
 int onepercent = amount /= 100;
```

At compile time, compiler will not be able to determine whether any of the if statement will result in true and setting of amount. To avoid this error you could do (at start) :

```
int amount=-1;
```

Now you will not get your compiler error and value of the amount will change in the if statement. P.S. ('If' is a statement not a loop)

Comment: Leave it 'unassigned'. Empty does not apply to `int`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, If the amount is not assigned in this case, it will generate a compile time error.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I still couldn't get what your first comment meant, if I leave amount to be unassigned and leave the if conditions , it will work?

Comment: Your reasoning was OK but you used the wrong word, that was all.

Answer (score 1):

There is chance of having inputbalk as null :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `if` is *not* a loop
2. considering `inputbalk` is `string`, it *can* be a `null`, you don't check for it, so *could* happen that it's your case.

Change your code, like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputbalk))
{
     amount = Convert.ToInt32(inputbalk);
     amount = 1;
}

else
{
    amount = Convert.ToInt32(inputbalk);
    amount = 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler cannot see that amount is definitely assigned. *You* know that inputBalk can't change between the first and second time it is evaluated, and that exactly one of the if conditions will be true, but the compiler doesn't check this. It sees only that there is a path where amount isn't assigned before it is used, which is disallowed.

You should use if/else instead of testing the same condition twice.

```
if (...)
{
    amount = 1;
}
else
{
    amount = 2;
}
```

Now the compiler can see that every possible path through the code causes amount to be definitely assigned.

There are also a number of other advantages: the code is more concise, easier to read and more maintainable. Furthermore, there is a slight performance benefit from not doing the same check twice.

Answer (score 1):

You could however also encounter an FormatException with the Convert.ToInt32() method. Consider using int.tryParse as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a blast:

```
if (!int.TryParse(inputbar.Text, out amount))
    amount = 1;
```