# C# Local variable won't mutate in if statement

Tags: c#

I am quite new the C# and I have googled the answer. The closest answer I have found was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205831/if-statement-cant-change-local-variable). But it doesn't help me.

I am trying to write a function that finds the biggest number in a string using loops and splicing only. For some reason, when the condition is met, the local variable big won't mutate in the if statements. I have tried to debug it by setting big = 34 when I hit a space, but even then it won't mutate the local variable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace parser
{
    class Sub_parser
    {
        // function to find the greatest number in a string
        public int Greatest(string uinput)
        {
            int len = uinput.Length;
            string con1 = "";
            int big = 0;
            int m = 0;

            // looping through the string
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                // find all the numbers
                if (char.IsDigit(uinput[i]))
                {
                    con1 = con1 + uinput[i];
                }

                // if we hit a space then we check the number value
                else if (uinput[i].Equals(" ")) 
                {
                    if (con1 != "")
                    {
                        m = int.Parse(con1);
                        Console.WriteLine(m);
                        if (m > big)
                        {
                            big = m;
                        }
                    }

                    con1 = "";

                }

            }

            return big;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string u_input = Console.ReadLine();
                Sub_parser sp = new Sub_parser();
                Console.WriteLine(sp.Greatest(u_input));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the input looks like?

Comment: Set breakpoints and use your debugger to step through the code and inspect your variables. Variables do mutate in `if()` statements. The problem is that you're appending all numbers to the same string, so for the input `12`, `2` will be compared to `12` and thus never be larger.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with local variables. If you think their values don't change it means there's a bug in the code. You don't explain *which* variable you are talking about though. Have you tried debugging your code? Perhaps the conditions are wrong and execution never enters the blocks that would modify that variable?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP said the `big` variable is the one that didn't change.

Comment: @KennethK. and that's why proper formatting matters.

Comment: *"I have tried to debug it by setting big = 34"* - That's not really debugging, that's mostly guessing and assuming.  *Debugging* would involve setting a breakpoint, then stepping through the functionality one operation at a time and observing the runtime values and behavior.  At some point during the execution of your program, an unexpected result will occur from a specific operation.  What is the *first* unexpected thing that happens when you debug?  What were the inputs to that operation?  What was the result?  What was the expected result?  Why?

Comment: Note that your code will never include the last item. I recommend Kristjan's solution.

Comment: ...how about decimals?

Comment: I have been testing with this input "I have 32 sheeps"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from your check in this statement :

```
else if (uinput[i].Equals(" "))
```

uinput[i] is a char, while " " is a string : [see this example](http://rextester.com/OCBR50808)

if you replace the double quotes by single quotes, [it works fine](http://rextester.com/WYJI79346)...

```
else if (uinput[i].Equals(' '))
```

And, as stated by the comments, the last number will never be checked, unless your input string ends by a space. This leaves you with two options :

- recheck again the value of con1 after the loop (which is not very good-looking)
- Rewrite your method because you're a bit overdoing things, don't reinvent the wheel. You can do something like (using System.Linq):

  ```
  public int BiggestNumberInString(string input)
  {
      return input.Split(null).Max(x => int.Parse(x));
  }
  ```

  only if you are sure of your input

Comment: i am aware that the last number won't be check. This is just a work in progress. I have been testing with the input "I have 32 sheeps" Thank you. I can't believe the answer was this simple! I know you can use split method to do this, I was trying to learn the syntax by using loops on purpose.

Comment: @jun Next time, don't forget to mention an example for an input string that you are trying. And your question might get closed by the community.

Answer (score 1):

When you give a number and a space in the keyboard you only read the number, no space.
So you have `uinput="34"`. 
Inside the loop, you check if the `m > big` only if `uinput[i].Equals(" ")`. Which is never. 
In general if you read a line, with numbers followed by space, it would ignore the last number.

One solution would be to append a " " into uinput, but i recommend splicing.

```
string[] numbers = uinput.Split(null);
```

Then iterate over the array.

Also, as said in another answer compare `uinput[i].Equals(' ')` because `" "`represents a string, and you were comparing a char with a string.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Verjans mentioned, in order to make your code work you have to edit it like in his example.
Although there is still a Problem if you input a single number. The output would then be 0.

I would go for this Method:

```
public static int Greatest(string uinput)
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    foreach(string str in uinput.Split(' '))
    {
        numbers.Add(int.Parse(str));
    }

    return numbers.Max();
}
```